# What is the meaning of the globe icon next to some player names when searching for friends?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

When searching for people to add to the list of friends I noticed some people have this small icon of a globe next to their names:

[image: globe icon]

As far as I could tell it makes no difference in who I can/can't try to add. What does the icon actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This icon is related to the addition of emblems on players' profiles [in the Season 2 update on October 18th 2018](https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Update_Schedule#Season_2_2). When you achieve certain trophies, you have the option of displaying the associated emblem on your profile. This emblem will also show up when you navigate to your friends list.

The emblem you referenced in the image is the **Tenacious Adventurer - Bronze** emblem and [can be obtained by receiving 5 quest trophies](https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Trophies#General).

To set an emblem on your profile:

1. Select the *Menu* button in the top-right corner
2. Select *Player Info*
3. Select *Set Emblem*